# Android: Search from listView with editText and custom tags

Tags: android, listview

I have a program which stores items to database, and I want to make a search view for those items. Database items have a name and a set of tags linked to them (These tags, to be exact: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2566). In the search view, I want to list all the items in the db and within the same view, filter the results by name, using input in editText, and by the tags, by showing the available tags as a tag cloud. Does anyone know an example or tutorial where similar search structure would have been implemented?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Nothing yet, as I really don't know where to start.

Comment: In order to avoid downvote please try to explain your attempt before asking for answers and try to be precise. We are here to guide you not to solve entire user story. Considering you as new to community I will give you upvote to balance your loss in reputation as I want you to keep posting your queries in future.

Answer (score 0):

You may into this tutorial: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

You can use filters on the listview as shown in the above example. You can implement your own filters for custom functionality. Use of onTextChangedListener depends upon your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is code snippet of how to implement simple search function on edittext text change. Hope you get an idea

```
searchInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {

            CenterRepository.getInstance().getSearchResultCollection().getListOfSearchResult().clear();

            //Iterate over reference models
            for (ReferenceModel model :
                    CenterRepository.getInstance().getXRefModelCollection().getListOfReferenceModels()) {

                //if serach key is present in model name or model number
                if (model.getModelName().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString()) || model.getModelNumber().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString())) {

                    //add to search collection
                    CenterRepository.getInstance().getSearchResultCollection().addToSearchResultsCollection(model);
                }
            }

            //display search results
            renderListData(true);

        } else {

            //display all models
            renderListData(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count) {

    }
});
```